# Why I get mergeMapTo is not a function when using rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs6, angular-observable

I recently upgrade app from Angular 5 to Angular 8 and I change the imports
rxjs to match the new version of rxjs which is rxjs 6 now.

I have the following import statement:

```
import { map, mergeMap, startWith, mergeMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

An I'm using it inside the component:

```
public myObservable: any;

 myMethod() {

    this.myObservable = timer(1, 1000);
        this.myObservable
        .mergeMapTo(this.myService.loadData(this.myId))
        .subscribe((data) => {
                this.myData = data;                
            }, (errRes)=>{
            console.log(errRes);
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the new RXJS syntax, by wrapping those operators in the `pipe()`
like so:

```
public myObservable: any;

     myMethod() {

        this.myTimer = timer(1, 1000);
            this.myObservable
            .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.myService.loadData(this.myId)))
            .subscribe((data) => {
                    this.myData = data;                
                }, (errRes)=>{
                console.log(errRes);
            });
      }
```

See this article for more details:
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/